Capturing variations in string in Swift Regex
I would like to be able to capture two possibilities for the way something can be written. As I work through a large string with multiple entries, I am noticing that some entries are written differently but mean the same thing.
What I would like is to be able to use the same variable but capture variations on the same word.
I am aware that this example below is incorrect, but was wondering if there was a way to do something along the lines of this?
struct NotamRegexPatterns {

static let holdingPoint: Regex = Regex {
        Capture {
            "HOLDING POINT" || "HLDG POINT"
        }
    }

}


You can use ChoiceOf:
Capture {
    ChoiceOf {
        "HOLDING POINT"
        "HLDG POINT"
    }
}

Or you can always just fallback to regex literal syntax:
Capture {
    /HOLDING POINT|HLDG POINT/
}


Legend! Thank you
